# htmlentities error when passing from a modal

Tags: laravel

New to Laravel, please bare with.

**Error:**

```
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: /var/www/html/willow/resources/views/emails/valuation.blade.php)
```

The **modal** from which it is being sent:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['EnquiryController@valuationRequest']]) !!}
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control has-feedback', 'placeholder' => 'Name']) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control has-feedback', 'placeholder' => 'Email Address']) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::text('telephone', null, ['class' => 'form-control has-feedback', 'placeholder' => 'Telephone Number']) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::text('house_number', null, ['class' => 'form-control has-feedback', 'placeholder' => 'House name / number']) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::text('postcode', null, ['class' => 'form-control has-feedback', 'placeholder' => 'Postcode']) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::textarea('message', null, ['class' => 'form-control has-feedback', 'placeholder' => 'Message', 'rows' => '5']) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="button black" value="Register">
                </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
```

and the function:

```
public function valuationRequest(ValuationRequest $request)
 {       
    // dd($request->all());
         Mail::send('emails.valuation',
                ['name' => $request['name'],
                'email' => $request['email'],
                'telephone' => $request['telephone'],
                'house_number' => $request['house_number'],
                'postcode' => $request['postcode'],
                'message' => $request['message'],
                ],
            function ($message) use ($request) {
                $message->to('paolo@bigg.co.uk', 'Paolo Resteghini')->subject('Valuation Request - Willow Lettings');
            });
         Session::flash('flash_message', 'Your request has been sent.');
     return redirect(URL::previous());
}
```

The contents of the DD are perfect. All of the requests are populated as expected, but when trying to go through the rest of the function it fails with the error above.

emails.valuation:

```
Hello, <br><br>

You have received a new valuation request via the Willow Lettings website. Here they are: <br><br>

<b>Name:</b> {{ $name }}<br>
<b>Email:</b> {{ $email }}<br>
<b>Phone:</b> {{ $telephone }}<br>
<b>House number:</b> {{ $house_number }}<br><br>
<b>Postcode:</b> {{ $postcode }}<br><br>
{{ $message }}
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a htmlentities() request in your code, though? Can you show the view the message is talking about?

Comment: htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: /var/www/html/willow/resources/views/emails/valuation.blade.php)

Comment: Does `valuation.blade.php` contain anything other than that modal?

Comment: please, can you show us the valuation.blade.php code. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry gents! Here it is: http://pastebin.com/2tY2s94H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, this is a problem with your `message` variable. As you can see from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail#sending-mail):

> Note: A `$message` variable is always passed to e-mail views, and allows the inline embedding of attachments. So, you should avoid passing a `message` variable in your view payload.

In other words, you should change `message` into something else like `msg`.

```
'msg' => $request['message'],
```

Then, in your blade file, reflect that change:

```
{{ $msg }}
```